# XmlException: Root element is missing. C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, xmlserializer

I'm trying to send a `list<clase_A>` by `xmlSerializer`, from an interface to unity.

Here is my server code:

```
using (connectedTcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient())
            {               
                using (NetworkStream stream = connectedTcpClient.GetStream())
                {
                    int length;
                    XmlSerializer xmls = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Clase_comando>));
                                        
                    while ((stream.CanRead && (length = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0))
                    {
                        List<Clase_comando> com = null;
                        var b = new byte[10000];                                                      
                        com = (List<Clase_comando>)xmls.Deserialize(stream);
                            //Here i get the problem
                        

                    }
                }
            }
```

Here is the code of Visual Studio:

```
NetworkStream stream = socketConnection.GetStream();
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream);
sw.AutoFlush = true;
XmlSerializer xmls = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Clase_A>));

if (stream.CanWrite){
   z = My list

   byte[] b = new byte[10000];
   Stream st = new MemoryStream(b);
   xmls.Serialize(st, z);
   stream.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
   stream.Dispose();
   }
```

The problem is when I receive the interface data in unity, it trow this exception:

> ```
> XmlException: Root element is missing.  
> System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw (System.Exception e) (at <7fd195060d8c41448694ab221d3b56ca>:0)  
> System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowWithoutLineInfo (System.String res) (at <7fd195060d8c41448694ab221d3b56ca>:0)
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line

```
while ((stream.CanRead && (length = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0))
```

data is read from the `stream` to the `bytes`.
After that, there is either no data in the stream at all either the root is already missing.
So on the next line, the serializer reads from the corrupted stream:

```
com = (List<Clase_comando>)xmls.Deserialize(stream);
```

---

Try this code:

```
using (NetworkStream stream = connectedTcpClient.GetStream())
{
    var xmls = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Clase_comando>));
            
    var com = (List<Clase_comando>)xmls.Deserialize(stream);
}
```

Comment: Omg thnkx!!!! this worked!!!!!! u save me, im super happy tyyyyy!!!!

Comment: If this helped you, @Narsh, please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Afaik you can't directly (de)serialize into a `List<T>`.

You rather need a wrapper class like e.g.

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot]
public class Root
{
    [XmlArray]
    public List<Clase_comando> Comandos;
}
```

and

```
using (NetworkStream stream = connectedTcpClient.GetStream())
{
    int length;
    XmlSerializer xmls = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
                                    
    while ((stream.CanRead && (length = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0))
    {
        var b = new byte[10000];                                                      
        List<Clase_comando> com = ((Root)xmls.Deserialize(stream)).Comandos;                    
    }
}
```

And on the other side accordingly

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot]
public class Root
{
    [XmlArray]
    public List<Clase_A> Comandos;
}
```

and

```
XmlSerializer xmls = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));

if (stream.CanWrite)
{
    var root = new Root(){ Comandos = MyList };

    byte[] b = new byte[10000];
    using(var st = new MemoryStream(b))
    {
        xmls.Serialize(st, root);
        stream.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
    }
}
```

---

*Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: Yes i have the class, but still doesnt work. i thnk the problem is about how the list is serialized by xmlSerializer, i dont know....when unity tryes to deserialize (same class) its when the error is given, i dont know what to do,  I'm very overwhelmed cause i need to present it in 2 days